# How can I reject error to user while SQLite fail to select data

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, npm, promise

I'm facing a problem in SQLite. I want to return error message from the promise. If user search something in the database like `SELECT username FROM user WHERE username='something`

when a user runs the query and if something found in the database then it work properly. On the other hand if nothing found it's take too time for query and finally nothing return. Here is my query code with promise

```
selectOne(query){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.each(query, (err, rows) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
        resolve(rows)
      })
    })
  }
```

Suppose I'm checking if the username exists in a database. If not then a user can register. So that I need the error to be returned. But nothing happened

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if(err) reject(err);`?

Comment: `err` should be having something like `err.message`.

Comment: Ops. It's should